XCM fee payment with destination on-chain asset balance
Is there a way in XCM v3/v4 to charge a user XCM fees using something else than what's in the holding registry at the time the fees are to be taken?
Specifically, I'm talking about deducting a user's on-chain balance of some assets that have not been sent over XCM.
Currently any instructions sent over that involves transfers, appends a ClearOrigin instructions which makes it impossible to withdraw any other assets on the destination chain to pay for fees.
